# CSS table alternate row colors and hover colors

Tags: css, html-table, styling

I have a table with class table. The only styling so far is the table th. I'd like to use a CSS value to alternate between white and silver for the rows, and hover silver for the entire row. Does anyone have the code for that?

---

```
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
   <th>heading</th>
   <th>heading 2</th>
   <th>heading 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='table'>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
    <td>col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='table'>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
    <td>col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='table'>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
    <td>col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That is the html example (as it's written in php)

CSS

```
.table {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}

.table th {
background-color: #333333;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

That's it so far. Looking for the values to use for I'm guessing the table tr css.

---

Saying different because even/odd doesn't work & it's dynamic php not strict html.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you've already set the background color of your table to white, you just need to set the alternate row and hover backgrounds, like so:

```
.table tr {
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: silver;
}

.table tr:hover {
    background: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Additionally, you probably don't need to repeat the `table` class on each row, FWIW. You can just target those rows using `.table tr` as I have done. If you're trying to make sure the table header and body styles don't interfere with each other, it's more semantic and just cleaner to wrap those elements in a `thead` and `tbody`:

```html
<table class='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>heading</th>
      <th>heading 2</th>
      <th>heading 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1</td>
      <td>col 2</td>
      <td>col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1</td>
      <td>col 2</td>
      <td>col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1</td>
      <td>col 2</td>
      <td>col 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: forgot that part lol

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with a little bit css, just use the n-th child selector, like this:

HTML:

```
<table class="alternate">
<tr>
  <td>Row Col 1 </td>
  <td>Row Col 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row Col 1 </td>
  <td>Row Col 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row Col 1 </td>
  <td>Row Col 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row Col 1 </td>
  <td>Row Col 2 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.alternate tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: silver;
}

.alternate tr {
  background-color: white;
}

.alternate tr:nth-child(2n):hover, .alternate tr:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

And here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wjwvdrv/1/), I hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: for some reason that doesn't work I've even tried the even/odd settings.

Comment: Edit: After seeing your updated question, try to give the tr tag another class, it may happens, because the tr Tag has the same class as the table tag. I know the table is generated with php, but there may is a option to rename the class of the tr Tags